# How are registers and other information preserved during function calls in C?

Tags: c, cpu-registers

Let us say I have three functions, `f1()`, `f2()`, and `f3()`. When `f1` is called, it stores information in CPU registers (and I imagine there is other important information as well).  Now, depending on a condition that is unknown at compile-time, `f1` will call either `f2` or `f3`.  `f2` and `f3` use very different registers, some of which may overlap with those used by `f1`.  Is the following reasoning correct?

The compiler knows which registers a particular function needs during its execution. Therefore, when `f1` calls either `f2` or `f3`, the function call code preserves those registers that `f2` or `f3` use on the stack, regardless of whether or not they are being used by `f1`.

Or is there some other mechanism by which the compiler preserves registers so that the function that is being returned to doesn't lose its data?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are looking for, because 1. every compiler may perform things differently (as that is dependent on e.g.: the target machine), 2. This is not specified in the programming language standard and 3. it may change depending on calling convention and optimization used

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to understand how function calls work.  I am trying to understand things like this: if I'm in a function that calls a shared library function, what is it that preserves things like data on the registers.  An answer pointed out that, since the compiler has no knowledge of what that function would need, it's up to the called function itself to preserve things, is it not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think as others have stated the arguments for a function are typically sent down via a number of registers (thereafter on the stack). Which registers are used depends on the compiler – for `gcc` see GNU C/assembler: http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/gasexamples/

A number of principles worth noting:

1. stack frame
2. caller (the function calling f1) and callee functions (your f1, f2... functions)
3. volatile and non-volatile registers. For your question you only don't need to worry about non-volatile registers.

Each function has a stack frame, this is an expandable block of the stack that temporarily stores data that needs to be loaded in and out of registers.

Before each function call (to the callee from the caller) the values you wish to pass down, i.e. your arguments, will be placed in a number of preordained registers (typically 4-6 depending on a the compiler – see link); if there are more arguments than the number of preordained registers then these additional values are stored on the stack (typically the callers stack frame).

If these preordained registers are being used by the caller, then the compiler will push these values onto the caller's stack frame before assigning the arguments to the registers before making the call to the callee (e.g. your f1 function). Once the called function (callee) returns, these values are restored to their respective registers from the stack.

It doesn't matter how or what order a series of functions are called the same system is followed when the compiler converts your C code to assembly/opcode.

Answer (score 6):

Recall that a programming language is a specification in a document. For [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29), read  [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

[Registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register) do not exist in C (in other words, the nearly obsolete `register` keyword is no more related to processor registers). They only matter in machine code (often *generated* by a C compiler).

However, the code generated by a given compiler (for a given instruction set and target system) obey to some conventions, notably the [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) and the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) (read the [system V x86-64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) governing Linux for an example). Thes conventions define how registers should be used, and which registers are callee-saved or caller-saved. [Register allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_allocation) is a difficult part of an [optimizing compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler)'s job.

Often the compiler would emit code to spill some of the registers content into the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack). And a given register can be used for several things (e.g. it could keep two different variables, if they occur in different places in the same function).

In general the calling convention does not depend upon the called function (recall that you can make indirect calls thru function pointers), but mostly of its signature.

Answer (score 5):

> "The compiler knows which registers a particular function needs during its execution."

No, it will generally not know this.

For one reason, a function can be from a (third party) library about which the compiler knows nothing. For another reason, what if that function calls another function, and another etetera?

The compiler will just push all "suspect" registers onto the stack and pops them before returning.